# Otherwise on $urlRouterProvider redirects to a state when it shouldn't in unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I use ui-router in my code and here is how I define states in my application:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('base', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '../views/base.html',
            controller: 'BaseCtrl'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('base.all', {
            url: '^/home',
            templateUrl: '../views/all.html',
            controller: 'AllCtrl'
        });

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

I'm unit testing the code which do this:

```
    $state.transitionTo('login');
```

and in my jasmine test I check:

```
   expect($state.current.name).toEqual('login');
```

Unfortunately, this ends up with the failed test with the following message:

```
Expected 'base.all' to equal 'login'.
```

I figured out that the problem most certainly is related to  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise as it makes my code go to 'base.all' instead of the 'login' state. To prove this I commented out the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise statement and then my test started to pass.

Any ideas why this happens? And what is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide more info about the test case and the code that you want to test. Maybe the change comes from some other place.

Answer (score 0):

Could you exchange the transitionTo() call for a go() call?

according to [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state/#methods_transitionto), unless you have some specific need you should use go()

Comment: I did and unfortunately it did not help.